# What's the standard folder structure for zsh?

Tags: zsh, directory-structure

In order to organize my zsh custom files folder structure, is there a standard directory structure for zsh?

I'm not talking about Oh-My-Zsh or any other framework, but for "vanilla" zsh custom files.

From now, I've seen this type of directory structure:

```
~/.zsh/
      custom/
            plugins/
            themes/
```

or

```
~/.zsh/
      functions/
      themes/
      library/
```

Comment: If you invoke `man zshall` and scroll to nearly the end, the section titled `FILES`, you see the files and directories which are of special importance to zsh. You will see there that you have pretty much freedom in organizing your files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no standard folder structure. Zsh lets you organize your files in almost any way you like.

There are a couple of rules, though:

- By default, Zsh looks for dotfiles in `$HOME`.
- To keep your Zsh dotfiles elsewhere, create a file `~/.zshenv` and, in there, assign `$ZDOTDIR` to the dir where you want to keep the rest of your dotfiles (and make surr you do not put anything else in `.zshenv`).
- `.zshrc` is generally the only Zsh dotfile you need. Most of the others are there for legacy reasons only.
- There is no standard location for the `$HISTFILE`, but on macOS and Debian, `/etc/zshrc` sets it to `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zsh_history`.
- There is no standard location for user functions (including themes and completions). Instead, any dir you add to your `$fpath` will be searched for functions. Examples in the Zsh documentation put custom functions in `~/myfns` or `~/myfuncs`.
- Shared functions should go to `/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions`. This dir is by default in every user’s `$fpath`.
- The completion dump file is saved by default to `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompdump`. You can change this by passing `-d <dumpfile>` when you call `compinit` (which you should call once and only once).
- Completion cache files are saved by default to `${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zcompcache/`, but you can change this with `zstyle ':completion:*' cache-path <dir>`.
- Plugins are not a standard part of Zsh (they were made up by Oh-My-Zsh) and thus don't have any standard location or handling at all.